# Unable to send email JavaMail API in MFP 7.0 Java adapter

Tags: java, ibm-mobilefirst, jakarta-mail, geronimo

I am using below code send email via java adapter in MFP 7.0 it has attachment also.

```
try {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            sb.append("<p style='font-family:Sans-serif;font-size: 12px'>Dear Xyz,<br><br>Attachment :</p>");
            sb.append("<p style='font-family:Sans-serif;font-size: 12px'>Regards, <br><br>  Team");
            String mailHost = "10.x.x.x";
            String mailFrom = "xyz@xyz.com";
            String mailTo = email;
            String mailSubject = "Subject";
            String mailBody = sb.toString();
            String mailAttachment = "" + fileName;

            Properties properties = System.getProperties();
            properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", mailHost);

            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(mailFrom));
            Address[] toAddress = null;

            if (mailTo != null) {
                toAddress = InternetAddress.parse(mailTo);
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
            }

            message.setSubject(mailSubject);

            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setContent(mailBody, "text/html");
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            String attachmentLocation = mailAttachment;
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(attachmentLocation);
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            messageBodyPart.setFileName(new File(attachmentLocation)
                    .getName());
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
            message.setContent(multipart);

            Transport.send(message);
        } catch (AddressException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I am getting the below error.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.geronimo.mail.handlers.HttpHandler cannot be cast to javax.activation.DataContentHandler jax rs
```

Kindly suggest on this issue as the class HttpHandler is from worklight-jee-library.jar which i am unable override. Is their any alternative for sending email with attachment from Java adapter.

Comment: It looks like you're using the Gnu version of JavaMail.  You'll probably have more luck if you can switch to the [JavaMail reference implementation](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home).  If the Gnu version is embedded in the worklight library, and you can't change it, you'll probably need to contact IBM for help.

Comment: @arun punnath, any updates in this question?

Answer (score 0):

We do it a bit differently...

1. In the application logic:

   ```
   ...
   ...    
   for (var i = 0; i < devices.resultSet.length; i++) {
       var sendResult = com.SendMail.SendMail.sendMail(devices.resultSet[i].email, devices.resultSet[i].serial, devices.resultSet[i].manufacturer, devices.resultSet[i].days);
       results.push(sendResult);
   }
   ...
   ```
2. And the Java code (stored in server/java/com/SendMail/SendMail.java) - you will obviously need to change the implementation details...:

   ```
   package com.SendMail;

   import java.util.*;
   import javax.mail.*;
   import javax.mail.internet.*;

   public class SendMail {
       public static String sendMail(String emailAddress) {
        String debugMessage = "";


             // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
             //String to = "the@email.address";
             String to = emailAddress;

             // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
             String from = "the-senders-email-address";

             Properties props = new Properties();
             props.put("mail.smtp.host", "the.host.name.com");
             props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");

             // Get the default Session object.
             Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);

             try{
                // Create a default MimeMessage object.
                MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

                // Set From: header field of the header.
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

                // Set To: header field of the header.
                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));

                // Set Subject: header field
                message.setSubject("the email subject line");

                // Now set the actual message
                message.setText("the email body message");


                // Send message
                Transport.send(message);
                debugMessage="Email sent successfully to " + emailAddress;

             } catch (MessagingException mex) {
                mex.printStackTrace();
                debugMessage=mex.toString();
             }

             return debugMessage;
       }
   }
   ```